# How to get "rev" attribute of Couchbase document using Spring Data for Couch in Java

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

I wish to know if there is efficient way to check if a Couchbase document is modified. And there is Scheduled Cron Job which checks every 15 min or some specified time interval.

Going through the contents is always an option but is there an efficient way to do this.

"rev" attribute of document seems to interesting, all I observed each time the document is modified rev attribute of document metadata gets updated. So I thought of using this to check if the document is modified.

Any suggestions please.

Have a nice day. Thank you.

Comment: Also I have come across this CAS value. Which is provided by Spring Data. Can I use this for my usecase?

Answer (score 2):

CAS is the right way to check if the document has been modified. Both pessimistic and optimistic locking are also supported by couchbase:

https://blog.couchbase.com/optimistic-or-pessimistic-locking-which-one-should-you-pick/